# Дождаться выполнения всех условий

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо дождаться выполнения нескольких условий

1. Окончание общего таймера (_TimeOver);
2. Окончания текущего таймера (_CurrentTimer);
3. Окончание проигрывания аудио (если в момент окончания вышеназванных событий 1 и 2 оно проигрывается) (_AudioInstructionEnd).

C событие 1 можно поймать через deferred объект.
А вот с событиями 2 и 3 возникают проблемы - при каждом нажатии на кнопку их состояние обновляется. Логика для этих двух событий, насколько я понимаю, вряд ли будет отличатся.

Должно получится что типа:

```
$.when(_TimeOver, _CurrentTimer, _AudioInstructionEnd).then(Finish); //когда выполнены все условия запустить функцию финиш
```

Comment: для полноты картины не хватает описания того, что находится в переменных.

Comment: Это условные deferred объекты которые всплывают по завершению событий (_CurrentTimer - по выполнению setTimeout, _AudioInstructionEnd - по завершению проигрывания аудио)

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function(){
  // В Deferred-объектах делаем что-то, при завершении, вызываем resolve для изменения состояния
  // В примерах это просто таймеры
  let _TimeOver = $.Deferred(obj => {
    setTimeout(() => obj.resolve(), 1500);
  });
  let _CurrentTimer = $.Deferred(obj => {
    setTimeout(() => obj.resolve(), 1700);
  });
  let _AudioInstructionEnd = $.Deferred(obj => {
    setTimeout(() => obj.resolve(), 2000);
  });
  
  // Собираем все Deffered-объекты в один и когда он успешно разрешится, выполнится done, иначе - fail
  $.when(_TimeOver, _CurrentTimer, _AudioInstructionEnd).done(r => console.info('Ho-ho-ho!')).fail(e => console.info(':('));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, поздравляю, Ваша шифровка настолько хороша, что не знаю что она тут делает, под этим ответом :)